# Is it possible to apply CSS3 box shadows inline to HTML E-mails?

Tags: templates, html-email, css

Is it possible to apply the following box shadow to the CSS of an HTML E-mail template?

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 62px 25px rgba(223,231,232,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 62px 25px rgba(223,231,232,1);
box-shadow: 1px 3px 62px 25px rgba(223,231,232,1);
```

Or will I need to use images of the shadow and insert them into to table?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is only supported in a [few email clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). You are better off using images if you want 100% support

Comment: Images regularly get blocked by email clients though... :/

Comment: Not if you embed the image as a base64 encoded string.

Comment: @Ralph many email providers clip emails beyond a certain data threshold, so I don't see base64 encoding the image data as a viable option either.

Comment: @rawkfist0215 I use base64 encoded images in emails for years now and tested it with multiple popular mail clients/providers like Gmail, Hotmail, Outlook and others with not a single problem. Images get shown right away because there is no security risk compared to an image that contains a image url.

Comment: @Ralph this is not the only source to argue this, but see: https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/should-we-stop-inlining-styles-in-emails-8c3b64f0d407

'A lighter HTML means it’s faster to initially download. But it can also help avoid having your emails clipped by certain email clients. For example, the desktop webmail of Gmail clips any content after the first 102 Kb of an email. A subscriber has to click on a “View entire message” link in order to display the email entirely.'

Comment: @rawkfist0215 "A subscriber has to click on a “View entire message” link in order to display the email entirely"... I was talking about the full message.

TS was asking if box shadow were possible. The selected answer suggests using images and Jamie Robinson replied that images would get blocked on which I replied that you can get images shown right away if you base64 encode them. It seemed obvious to me that we we're talking about the full email, not just the first portion of it. Nuff said, I rest my case ;)